# How to dismiss and pop to viewcontroller simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

My home viewcontroller is Tabbarcontroller

- From tabbar i navigate to (A) Viewcontroller (TabarViewcontroller
  -> A (Viewcontroller)
- From A (Viewcontroller) i push  (B) Viewcontroller
- From B (Viewcontroller) i Present  (C) Viewcontroller
- When i dismiss (c) Viewcontroller i want to show (A) Viewcontroller
  or (Home) TabbarviewController

So, I want to first dismiss presented viewcontroller and then I want to pop my previous pushed controller

Here is my navigation flow

```
From Tabbarviewcontroller 
1-  let aVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "a") as! OrderListingViewController
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aVC, animated: true)

From A viewcontroller 
2- let bVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "b") as! OrderListingViewController
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bVC, animated: true)

From B viewcontroller 
        let cVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "c") as! RejectOrderViewController
        cVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        cVC.definesPresentationContext = true
        cVC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        self.tabBarController?.presentVC(cVC)
```

**so from C Viewcontroller when i dismiss i want to show Tabbarviewcontroller or (A) ViewController**

Comment: do you have idea of UNwindSegue ??

Answer (score 3):

You have to dismiss the `ViewController C` in the following way.

`self.presentingViewController` will give the previous view controller object.

**Move to Root view controller**

```
  let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
  self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
      presentingVC?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
  }
```

**Move to previous controller**

If you need to previous view controller instead of root view controller then you have to just to a popViewController

```
let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
 self.dismiss(animated: true) {
      presentingVC?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
 }
```

**Move to a specific View Controller**

```
    let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            if let  destinationVC =  presentingVC?.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0 is <Your Destination Class>}).first {
                presentingVC?.navigationController?.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)
            }
        }
```

`<Your Destination Class>` replace with your destination class name.

Comment: it's navigate to root navigation controller (Login) i want to navigate it to A viewcontroller or Tabbarviewcontroller

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController B, you can write below code.

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY BELOW CODE

self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
          if controller.isKind(of: BVC) {
               self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
               break
          }
    }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below.

```
    // First, finding specific Navigation Controller and do pop.
    if let tabBarController = presentingViewController as?  UITabBarController {
        if let navigationController = tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
            // Then, dismiss self.
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present any model at that time form this model to not working pop view controller because this is presented model

for that you can use presented model parent Object Just like below

```
let presentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PresentVC") as! PresentVC
presentViewController.parentModel = self
self.presentViewController(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and dismiss view controller like this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 

           for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
                if controller.isKind(of: ViewControllers) {
                     parentModel.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
                     break
                }
           }
      }
```

and in block pop to your controller

Answer (score 0):

I had to use NotificationCenter to pop the previous controller.

```
let back_view = Notification.Name("back_view")
```

//Here's the action to close the actual controller

```
 @IBAction func closeWW(_ sender: Any) {
                
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: self.back_view, object: nil)
        })
    }
```

//Now, in the previous controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(popView), name: back_view, object: nil)
}

@objc func popView(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Maybe it's not the best answer, but it's work for me :)