# Swift Navigate from third ViewController to the first ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
    "PersonViewController") as? PersonViewController               
    
    vc?.names = persons[indexPath.row].emer!
    vc?.lastnames = persons[indexPath.row].mbiemer!
    vc?.delegate = self
    PersonViewController.indexes = indexPath.row 
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)

}`
```

I have a situations like this:

First ViewController is a collectionView, the second is a viewcontroller which is allowed to add new Person when I tap a button and works perfectly. I have used delegates and Core Data for local memory.

Also the second ViewController has another button to edit person. When I press button a new viewController appears with extension `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`. This viewcontroller consists of 2 buttons and 2 textfields. So when I want to press save button I want to go to the first viewcontroller (collectionview list) and when to press cancel to go back to the second viewcontroller.

Viewcontrollers are created with pushViewController method.

[image]

Please anyone help what should I use?

then in PersonViewController I call this inside button edit.

```
@objc func editCell(){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
    "ModalPresentationViewController") as? 
     ModalPresentationViewController

     navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    
}
```

Now the code in the las ViewController which is ModalViewController

```
@objc func savePerson(){
    if editNameTextfield.text == "" || editlastNameTextfield.text == ""{
        self.errorLbl.alpha = 1
    }
    else{
        let vc = ViewController()
        guard let textName = editNameTextfield.text else{
            return
        }
        guard let textLastName = editlastNameTextfield.text else{
            return
        }

        let index = PersonViewController.indexes
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[self] in
            if editDelegate != nil{
                self.editDelegate!.editPerson(editedName: textName, editedLastname: textLastName, index: index)
            }
        }
//            What should I call here??
       
    }
}
```

Comment: now it is edited. I just want a guide what to use to solve this

Comment: Are you handling your navigation via code or are you using Segues in Storyboard?

Comment: So what's the problem? `popToViewController` lets you go back to whatever view controller you want. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller

Comment: No I'm not using segues. In ViewController just embed Navigation Controller and used storyboard identifier to push to another ViewController. Also all views in 3 ViewControllers are created by code not in Main.storyboard

Comment: Can't save data with popToViewController. I success saving data only with popViewController but this method brings me back to previous screen not in the first one

Comment: Have you tried `popToRootViewController`? By the way, if you aren't using Segues, that means you should have quite a bit of code you could post instead of a hand-drawn explanation. That would be *very* helpful to actually *duplicate* whatever issue you are facing. Strip things down - it sounds like you have 4 VCs... A, B, C, and the navigation controller. Add *minimal* logic/views to each to duplicate. Post that.

Comment: I puted some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
func popTo(_ type: AnyClass) {
    guard let controllers = navigationController?.viewControllers else {return}
    
    for controller in controllers {
        if controller.classForCoder == type {
            navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke the function depending on the condition as:

```
popTo(A.classForCoder())
```

**EDIT:** Above solution works only if ViewControllers B and C presented via a navigation controller and are in the same navigation stack.

Since you present the ViewController C modally, below answer should work:

Make these changes to your ViewController B that is presenting C:

```
class B: UIViewController, PresenterDelegate {
// some functions

    func popToPrevious() {
        navigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
    }

    @objc func editCell(){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: 
        "ModalPresentationViewController") as? 
         ModalPresentationViewController
        vc.presenterDelegate = self

        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

And in your ViewController C:

```
class C {
    var presenterDelegate: PresenterDelegate? = nil

    //

    @objc func savePerson(){
        //
        //
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.presenterDelegate?.popToPrevious()
        })
    }
}
```

Also add PresenterDelegate protocol to a new file or below ViewControllers B or C

```
protocol PresenterDelegate {
    func popToPrevious()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good idea but still can't get to the A ViewController. I have tried a lot of solutions like this. The problem is that I forgot to mentions is that this function I invoke inside a dismiss completion because C- ViewController is a present modal. So every solution brings me back to the B - View Controller. I have tried also with popToRootViewController but still nothing

Comment: This is exactly what is my problem about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669698/how-to-dismiss-and-pop-to-viewcontroller-simultaneously but still doesn't work for me

Comment: Hey Donald, since you stated "PushVC" between B and C in your diagram, this solution was based on the assumption that A, B, C are in the same navigation stack. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: yeap my mistake B to C -> present not push

Comment: Made some changes, let me know :)

Comment: Solved! This was genius, Thank you very much!

Comment: Except when call dismiss the animated is better to  be false :p

Comment: Yeah, I did not pay any attention to animations at all :) I would appreciate if you accept my answer, so the community can benefit from it too.

Comment: Sorry first time posting a question, I did it